# Laravel post from modal tries to GET instead of POSt

Tags: laravel, post, get, routes, modal-dialog

The modal gets data from the @foreach and displays them. And from the form it posts the data entered to the next POST route {{ route('user.give') }}. However, it keeps trying to perform a GET request to a different route(precisely the route just above it). Please help, thank you for helping

```
@section('content')
    @if (session('status'))
        <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
            {{ session('status') }}
        </div>
    @endif

    @if(count($orgs) > 0)
        @foreach($orgs as $org)
        <div class="card m-1 col-md-3 p-0">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="{{ asset('storage/'.$org->logo) }}" alt="{{ $org->name }} logo" />

            <div class="card-body">
                <span class="card-title"><strong><i class="fa fa-church"></i> {{ $org->name }}</strong></span>
                <div class="small"><i class="fa fa-exchange-alt"></i> {{ $org->alias }}</div>

                <p class="card-text"></p>
                <button class="btn btn-outline-primary rounded-0" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter">
                    <i class="fa fa-credit-card"></i>
                    Give
                </button>
                <a href="{{ route('user.oneclick.create', ['id' => $org->id]) }}" class="btn  btn-outline border-dark text-dark rounded-0"><i class="fa fa-cogs"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        @endforeach
    @else
        <p>Sorry, there's no match for your search.</p>
    @endif
```

**and right below is the modal. It is actually continuation of the code above. The modal actually comes up, the issue only occurs at the point of posting**

```
<!-- form modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalCenterTitle">Details</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <cite>You are about to give to {{ $org->name }}</cite>
      <!-- form -->
        <form method="POST" action="{{ route('user.give') }}">
            @csrf
            <input type="hidden" name="organisation_name" value="{{ $org->name }}">
            <input type="hidden" name="organisation_id" value="{{ $org->id }}">
            <input type="hidden" name="organisation_email" value="{{ $org->email }}">
            <input type="hidden" name="organisation_logo" value="{{ $org->logo }}">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="amount">Amount</label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control rounded-0" name="amount" aria-describedby="amount" placeholder="e.g 5000" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="purpose">Purpose</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control rounded-0" name="purpose" placeholder="e.g tithe">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn  btn-outline border-dark text-dark rounded-0" id="proceed">
                Proceed
            </button>
        </form>
      <!-- //form -->
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline border-dark text-dark rounded-0" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <!-- <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button> -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- //form modal -->
@endsection
```

**Here are my routes**

```
Route::middleware('auth')->group(function (){
    Route::post('/user/search', 'HomeController@search')->name('user.search');
    Route::post('/user/give/', 'HomeController@give')->name('user.give');
    Route::get('/user/verify/{reference}', 'HomeController@verify')->name('user.verify');
```

It visits user.search instead of user.give and it does that with a GET

Comment: Hmm, maybe I didn't understand the question properly - when you submit your form (by clicking Proceed) which route is getting triggered? including arguments?

Comment: Is your modal opens according the exact record ?

Comment: yes it does @Akhtar Munir

Comment: you have wrapped your modal inside foreach ?

Comment: @Christophe Hubert, it tries to perform a GET on another POST route then it Laravel throws a methodNotAllowedException

Comment: Yes I have @Akhtar Munir, It still throws the error

Comment: Sometimes the form action doesn't work inside modals if it is repeating in a loop. So you need a little jquery to controller this. place your modal outside and make an object of the data in a loop, when you click on the modal button then set the data inside fields with jquery also set the form action with jquery and then check.

Comment: Ok @AkhtarMunir, thank you. I’ll try this out

Comment: When you place modal outside and remove the looped data, then you try does it work ? without data ?

Comment: Don’t really know jQuery so I am just searching for resources. @Akhtar Munir

Comment: Can give you shortcut for that, but when you place modal outside the foreach loop and remove all data from modal, and then you submit, does it target correct route ?

Comment: No it doesn’t, it targets the route just above the route I want to hit. And it tries to get instead of post

Comment: @AkhtarMunir I’d really appreciate the shortcut

Comment: Well can you tell me, if you have one form inside another form ?

Comment: No, the only form on that page is the one in the modal.

Comment: It's strange, can i see your routes ?

Comment: @Akhtar Munir, I have edited to add my routes

Comment: Your routes look fine, but if you have more routes then maybe there are some routes that overwrite each other.

Comment: I’ll check it out and let you know what’s up

Answer (score 0):

`$org` is not what you want in your modal: it is the last `$org` from your loop over your `$orgs` array since it is not inside the `@foreach` loop.

You need to generate your modal dynamically (through javaScript or other) when you click the button showing the modal.

Comment: Thanks @Christophe Hubert. Don't really understand your answer though, it worked perfectly on localhost. Problem started once I took it to production. I'd appreciate a code snippet or more explanation if it is convenient. I also tried putting it in the foreach but still no good. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Found it. Apparently I added a validation rule that was failing when the form was submitted. Since the validation error could not be sent to the modal it was performing a GET.

Breathing fresh air now. Thanks for your support y’all